# Finding the eigenvalues and eigen vectors of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$T:Z_5^{2x2}\rightarrow Z_5^{2x2}$$
$$T \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b\\
c & d \\ \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & a+b\\
b+c & c+d \\ \end{array} \right)$$

This is a linear transformation from the field of $Z_5$. I need to find all the  eigen values and all the eigen vectors.Since I'm new to this can you please give me some hints of how to get to the characteristic polynomial of $T$ in this case? thx

Comment: Treat the matrix as a vector $(a,b,c,d)$, and proceed as normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We can rewrite $T$ as
$$
T \pmatrix{a\\b\\c\\d} = \pmatrix{a\\a+b\\b+c\\c+d}
$$
(strictly speaking, this is how $T$ acts on the coordinate vector with respect to a particular basis).
How can we represent the above transformation as a matrix?

Comment: You should find that $T$ has one eigenvalue and one eigenvector.

Comment: so I have tried I found that the only eigenvalue is 1 correct?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: thx so much helpful